# Heroku app deployment successful but Node.js buildpack Times out and terminates nodejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, npm, buildpack

Heroku app deployment successful but Node.js buildpack Times out and terminates nodejs
Below is the log file

> mnyr_proj@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_be4f28beb225c85ac1653b53b7e76816
>   npm run serve

npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/tmp/build_be4f28beb225c85ac1653b53b7e76816/.heroku/node/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/tmp/build_be4f28beb225c85ac1653b53b7e76816/.heroku/node/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   'serve'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.12.0
npm info using node@v12.13.0
npm verb run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
npm info lifecycle  mnyr_proj@0.1.0~preserve:  mnyr_proj@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle v mnyr_proj@0.1.0~serve:  mnyr_proj@0.1.0

```
   >  mnyr_proj@0.1.0 serve /tmp/build_be4f28beb225c85ac1653b53b7e76816
   > vue-cli-service serve

    INFO  Starting development server...
    WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings5:36:47 PM

    warning  

   asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
   This can impact web performance.
   Assets: 
     img/fa-brands-400.fb0cbe85.svg (496 KiB)
     img/fa-solid-900.9948e588.svg (369 KiB)
     js/chunk-3cb9bc02.323e1d11.js (1.52 MiB)
     js/chunk-46d6fd27.5c2863c6.js (921 KiB)
     js/chunk-vendors.76662662.js (1.39 MiB)

    warning  

   entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
   Entrypoints:
     app (1.74 MiB)
         css/chunk-vendors.7e449d15.css
         js/chunk-vendors.76662662.js
         css/app.09d2c403.css
         js/app.063310d7.js



     App running at:
     - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 

     It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
     Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/

     App is served in production mode.
     Note this is for preview or E2E testing only.
```

-----> Timed out running buildpack Node.js
Terminated
/app/tmp/buildpacks/a104ebb80184ba556a3457859a381585c1c182694d8086bfcdabe39f3fe5857835812b209be5647b385deaddf7afa081b0f0c5d9d1683b767fb8abc0c3b79cc0/lib/monitor.sh: line 1: kill: (2373) - No such process
 !     Push failed

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this, I have the same issue

Comment: @MatthewBarnden, I currently have the same issue. Did any of you find a solution?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but for me it looks like buildpack runs `serve` action. So instead of during image build buildpack starting webserver to serve files and then dies from timeout.

Suddenly I'm newby in CNB so I have no idea what's wrong.